# Why does resignFirstResponder reset contentOffset on a UITextView?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, resignfirstresponder

No matter which settings I try to change, `resignFirstResponder` always forces the text to scroll to the top of a `UITextView`

I would like the keyboard to disappear but the content offset to remain the same.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a `UIScrollView` bug in iOS 8. Hopefully in iOS 9 they fix it. I only assume that its a bug because `resignFirstResponder` didn't have this behavior in iOS 7. Maybe its a feature.

The only way I found to prevent `resignFirstResponder` and `setText` from resetting the `contentOffset` was the following:

**Swift:**

```
textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false
```

**Objective C**

```
textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
```

Another reason I think its a bug is because the documentation says that it is set to NO by default, but when you print out the variable without setting it, its true.

More info on `NSLayoutManager` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000371-SW15)

Answer (score 2):

in viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

add this function

```
 - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
[_textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([_textView.text length], 0)];
}];
}
```

Comment: I did try this. What happened for me is it would jump to the top, then animate down. Not exactly the solution I was looking for.

It didnt keep the contentOffset the same, the content offset still gets reset to (0,0), then it scrolls down to the bottom of the page.